# Select query with where clause that requires a range of varchars

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, where-clause, varchar

Here's the thing, I have a stored procedure which must select products from the database, but only those which fit in between the start product code, and the finish product code which the user chooses and get sent to the procedure.

Now the product codes are varchars, and they may contain numbers AND letters, like `01`, `01B` and `02A` may be product codes, and the procedure must be able to select all the values in between the user selected ranges.

I'm having trouble with such where clause doing it like this:

```
...
SELECT ...
WHERE ... AND
 ProductCode >= @IniProCod
 AND 
 ProductCode <= @FinProCod
...
```

The available product codes are shown to the user via a previous query which returns only available product codes, so there should be no problem with non existant values.

I also tried evaluating them as text, although they are received as varchars by the procedure anyway, and since this is inside a dynamic SQL query it actually looks something like this:

```
...
SELECT ...
WHERE ... AND
 ProductCode >= '''+@IniProCod+'''
 AND 
 ProductCode <= '''+@FinProCod+''''
...
```

And when I try to execute it it returns either the first row, or a set of rows that has very little to nothing to do with the actual values I'm sending to the procedure, so I don't even think it's comparing the values as strings at all.

I leave out code that has nothing to do with the issue, the query actually works alright without this range where clause.

So any ideas?

**Edit:**

I also tried using BETWEEN but got the same outcome.

And I'm very certain it is just not comparing the variables as text even when they are declared as varchars and I'm using apostrophes on them, and this is only happening on this procedure. I tested this same clause on a clean select query and it does behave as it should, comparing each character for what they are. If I set the initial values as `0` and `29` respectively it will give me a range from `01` to `29` which are the values contained within that range, but when these same values are given to the stored procedure it will return a range from `01` which is the first value, to `03F`, which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you'll need to have your application figure out the list of product codes based on the start & end codes, then send that list to the stored procedure. Your SQL would just contain something like `AND ProductCode IN (@myProductCodeList)`.

Comment: This is a good idea, if you are committed to these codes.  SQL Server certainly can sort and compare by text.  But if your codes aren't ordered in the same way the database sorts the text... well, then a range isn't going to match.  If you can push the list to an "IN" like iKnowKungFoo says, that might be a pretty direct answer.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, I don't really have much control over the application outside the procedure calling though, so I don't know for sure if I'd be able to sort it out before executing the procedure, that's why I was focusing on the query instead.